# How to Poweroff /suspend WinCE 6 device from C#

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I have been doing few programming in WinCE 6 device for sometime now.For one of my requirement  I want to suspend the device after some time . I m not sure how to do it.

If its PC , I know this works

```
Process.Start("shutdown","/s /t 0");
```

Not Sure for WinCE devices .Thanks .

Device: WinCE ,using C#

Comment: You want to restart the device or close? Close only the screen you can set up from os.

Comment: @kostasch. I want to close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's is no command line support to shutdown the WindowCE. you can use PInvoke the core.dll and call P/Invoke [ExitWindowsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416523.aspx)

```
[Flags]
public enum ExitFlags
{
  Reboot = 0x02,
  PowerOff = 0x08
}

[DllImport("coredll")]
public static extern int ExitWindowsEx(ExitFlags flags, int reserved);

...

ExitWindowsEx(ExitFlags.PowerOff, 0);
```

----- Updated ---------

Try with [GwesPowerOffSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee478435%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx) it's for WinCE 5.0. This is exactly what you are looking for. It's in the same core dll file.

Comment: Hi , It doesnt work , says this " Can't find entry point ExitWindowsEx in PInvoke DLL coredll"